# Can not remove sub view from tableview custome cell

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell

When table will be scroll it will repeat `subview` on cell, I am use below code for display embedded view on `tableview custome` cell. any one know so please help me. How to resolve this issues.

```
long tag = 100 + indexPath.row;
URLEmbeddedView *embeddedView = [custom.contentView viewWithTag:tag];

if ([custom.contentView viewWithTag:tag]) {
    [embeddedView loadURL:@"" completion:nil];
    [embeddedView removeFromSuperview];
}

embeddedView = [[URLEmbeddedView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 60, 220, 110)];
//URLEmbeddedView *embeddedView = [[URLEmbeddedView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(custom.img_bgOther.frame.origin.x + 35, custom.img_bgOther.frame.origin.y + 50, 220, 110)];

embeddedView.tag = tag;
[custom.contentView addSubview:embeddedView];
[embeddedView loadURL:str_Website completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the code in your question is taken from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  The problem you describe is a consequence of cells being reused.  Cells for rows that have scrolled off screen are reused for rows that scrolling on screen.  Suppose row 0 is scrolled off screen.  It will have an embedded view with tag **100**.  And suppose it is reused for row 10.  The above code will try to find a view with tag **110** and remove it from its superview.  Since the tag does not match, the existing embedded view is not removed, and the new embedded view is added on top of it.

I would suggest you do things differently.  You shouldn't be adding and removing the embedded view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You have a custom cell, so just design the embedded view into it.  Create a `URLEmbeddedView` property in your custom cell class, so you can access that subview without having to use `viewWithTag`.  You can use that property to call the `loadURL:completion:` method with the correct values for the current row.

When cells are reused, the tableView will call the cell's `prepareForReuse` method.  So override that method in your custom cell class, and clear the loadURL/completion at that point.